# MOSS 2007 central admin shows a blank page

Tags: moss

Our central admin site always displays a blank page.
Could not find any errors in the error logs. No event logged in event viewer for this.
Breaking our heads with this issue.

Could anyone please help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set "enable 32 bit application" as False in the app pool account of the central admin site and it worked.